# Asynchronous Issues with Node.js SOAP requests

Tags: node.js, xml, api, soap

I am trying to make a request to the Quest API to create an employee drug test order. My request is below

```js
const questOption = { username, password, orderXml };

soap.createClientAsync(baseUrl).then( (client) => {
        let createOrderResult = client.CreateOrder(questOption)
        console.log("createOrderResult:", createOrderResult)
        return createOrderResult;
      })
      .then( (result) => {
      console.log("result:", result)
        const parsedResult = orderService.parseResponse(createOrderResult, "create");
      })
```

The console.log of the createOrderResult and result are returning undefined which makes it seem that the console.logs are running before the API request is completed. The parameters are correct and the xml format matches exactly what the Quest API docs requires. Below is a screenshot of what the quest API requires in the API request along with an example response from the API when an Error occurs

[image]
[image]

Also, I should mention that when I console.log(client), I receive a massive object. Happy to provide any other info! Appreciate any help on this

Comment: What does `client.CreateOrder(questOption)` return?

Comment: undefined as well. I just updated the post to reflect this too!

Comment: I guess there is your answer. The async code doesn't run before `createClientAsync` completes. It's just that `client.CreateOrder()` returns `undefined. Are you certain you are passing the parameters correctly? The signature says `CreateOrder(string username, string password, string orderXml)` which seems like three different parameters. But you pass in one object with all three of these. I don't know if that's accurate or not.

Comment: I've tried client.CreateOrder(username, password, orderXml) and am getting the same results. Maybe an issue with the XML as you said? Although I would think the API would return an error and not leave the result as undefined

Comment: It certainly seems like the SOAP client doesn't work as expected. But I don't know why. The documentation clearly states it should return a string, yet you get `undefined` and it's not even an error. Might be an issue with the API you're consuming.